# "give to someone" vs. "give someone"

Tags: prepositions, verbs

Tell me please which of the following sentences is correct.

> 1. The best advice parents give their children is to be kind to others.
> 2. The best advice parents give **to** their children is to be kind to others.

It seems to me that both sentences might be correct.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**give** is a [double-object verb](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/double-object-verbs): the direct object is WHAT you give, and the indirect object is WHO you give it to. If the word order is verb-DO-IO, a **to** is required. If the word order is verb-IO-DO, no **to** is required.

> I gave a book **to** him
>   I gave him a book.

When you use the verb within a relative clause the direct object is at the front of the sentence, so either form is acceptable:

> the best advice that parents can give their children is....
>   the best advice that parents can give **to** their children is....

This [NGRAM](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=can%20give%20their%2C%20can%20give%20to%20their&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccan%20give%20their%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccan%20give%20to%20their%3B%2Cc0) shows that the version without **to** is more common.

Note that the idiomatic usage is to include the word **can**. This suggests that it is possible for parents to give this advice, rather than that they always give this advice.

Comment: *"To this end, I give **to** you the best and most important available knowledge ..."* - 
would be this case correct too?

Comment: @Sergey, yes that is correct, but it sounds quite old-fashioned, formal... even pompous. This NGram shows that including **to** in this context is extremely uncommon.  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+give+to+you+the%2C+I+give+you+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20give%20to%20you%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20give%20you%20the%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Thank you! It's from the book published in 2011, but the author of that book was born in 1908. Interesting that from that diagram the use of the expression *"I give you the.. "* decreases.

Comment: I wouldn't have answered this question as efficiently. Congrats.